# how to built a database for to sale online?

Tags: asp.net, database-design, point-of-sale

well i have a table my boss has made... they are 2 tables..

```
first where products are going to be has
(table A)

idinvoice (since table B)
idpruduct
description (it is the name of product)
quantity
unitPrice
TotalPrice

another table (i am going to call it table B)
idinvoice
date
deadline
type
idclient
saler (i consider it is sooo bad)
street
transport
status
Total
```

why do i believe it is bad?

because first the client is going to choose the product (but it doesn't have a idinvoice)
i have never made something as this, only on windows form, but i have never built a online point sale,

how tables do you believe I must to have? (what columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three tables. They might be something like:

1. Product: idpruduct, description (it is the name of product), unitPrice
2. Client: idclient, street
3. Invoice: idinvoice, idclient, saler, plus everything else related to a shipment or sale of one or more products.

You might also want:

1. Saler, or salesman: name, idnumber (perhaps idclient, too)

Does this sound close to correct, to start with?